# Kafka ConsumerGroupState explaination

Tags: apache-kafka

I saw the following constants in `ConsumerGroupState`. What situation would cause a consumer group hold DEAD or UNKNOWN state?

```java
UNKNOWN("Unknown"),
PREPARING_REBALANCE("PreparingRebalance"),
COMPLETING_REBALANCE("CompletingRebalance"),
STABLE("Stable"),
DEAD("Dead"),
EMPTY("Empty");
```

I think EMPTY means members are empty. PREPARING_REBALANCE means new consumer joins / old consumer left and COMPLETING_REBALANCE is similar to it.

My goal is to find a state which indicates the consumer group is inactive , and as I understand, I can simply take EMPTY state.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **Empty**: The group exists but no one is in it
- **Stable**: The rebalancing already took place and consumers are happily consuming.
- **PreparingRebalance**: Something has changed, and it requires the reassignment of partitions, so Kafka is the middle of rebalancing.
- **CompletingRebalance**: Kafka is still rebalancing the group. Why there are 2 states for that? More on that in a minute.
- **Dead**: The group is going to be removed from this Kafka node soon. It might be due to the inactivity, or the group is being migrated to different group coordinator.

taken from https://chrzaszcz.dev/2019/06/kafka-rebalancing/